# Open a External https website in salesforce1 on some action

Tags: salesforce1-app

I need to open a page from the external web application in saleforce1 app.on some custom action.
is there any way to achieve this scenario.

I tried to create a custom link on account object and try to open a web application in the visualpage with the iframe. but its not working with the saleforce1 app.

Can anyone help me out please ???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open an external web page, you have 2 options:

1 Use an iFram to embed the page. But you're saying that doesn't work. So the other option might be a fit.

2 Do a redirect. There's 3 options there.

2.1 Use a meta-refresh, like so

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

2.2 Use a piece of script that opens the page

```
<script>
  window.open('http://example.com');
</sript>
```

2.3 Use an `<a href='...'>` link in your VF page, and make the user click it, or let a script click it automatically. If you want to open the website/webapp in a new page, add the _blank target attribute.

```
<a href='...' target='_blank'>text</a>
```

It should open the link in a new window. If that doesn't work, try

```
<a onclick="window.open('...'); return false;">text</a>
```

You can not, though, open the page in the external device browser.

Comment: Yes,  But I want to open the page into the salesforce1 application only. in some visual page or canvas may be.. Is it Possible ?

Comment: I see. See my updated answer.